# Building errors on PIC-IoT development board

Tags: debugging, build, iot, pic

I'm trying to make an IoT project with the PIC-IoT development board. To start with the development, I have downloaded the source project given by microchip on the following github page:

https://github.com/microchip-pic-avr-solutions/pic-iot-aws-sensor-node

The problem comes when I open the project and whitout having modified anything I build the project and it gives me the folowing errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdMaY.png)

Do you know what these errors mean and how can I fix them?

The PIC-IoT has a PIC24FJ128GA705 and I'm using the MPLAB X v.6.10 and the compiler XC16 v.2.1

I don't understand what those errors mean. I'm expecting someone who knows how to fix the errors or what those errors mean and how should I try to fix them.

Thanks you all.